# Best practice when using ActiveModel Serializer to generate nested responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, active-model-serializers

Is this the only way to generate a response that has nested keys?

```
module Api
  module V20150315
    class ProductConfigurationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      cached
      delegate :cache_key, to: :object

      embed :ids, include: true

      attributes :id, :short_code, :rank

      has_many :delivery_product_configurations,
        serializer: Api::V20150315::DeliveryProductConfigurationSerializer

    end
  end
end
```

The `has_many` is a serializer which itself calls another serializer. Is the best way to do this right?

Are there alternative ways to do this? Is this the most semantic way?

-Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way as indicated in the [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md#has_many).

You do not need to specify the serializer for the `delivery_product_configurations` if it already has a serializer defined. You can refactor thus:

```
...
attributes :id, :short_code, :rank

has_many :delivery_product_configurations
...
```